# Comparing means of multiple response variables

Tags: repeated-measures

I am comparing means of ion intensities at many different chromatographic retention times for two non-paired groups (control and treated). So for example I have 6 control samples and 8 treated samples. At retention time 50, the control samples will have a mean ion intensity of 1000 and the treated samples have an ion intensity of 2000. At retention time 51 the control samples have a mean ion intensity of 400 and the treated samples have a mean ion intensity of 450. And so on for 360 different retention times. Is there an alternative to doing individual t-tests for each retention time (360 t-tests?). Maybe multiple t-tests can be programmed in R? Only two groups of samples are compared for this data but I would like to compare up to 4 groups, so this question would also apply to one-way ANOVAs.

Comment: Do you have multiple response variables, or one response variable measured at different times? It sounds like the latter.

Answer (score 1):

For people outside your field, please tell us more about ion intensities. Are they always positive, or always positive or zero? Do they tend to be symmetrically distributed for given conditions or are they skewed?

There would be a widespread statistical aversion here to lots of t-tests, regardless of easy or how awkward it is to set up their computation. You just set yourself up for another problem, how to interpret the results, especially if they are contradictory and the comparisons can't be considered independent.

I would lean to thinking of a functional dependence of ion intensities on retention time, if that makes physical or chemical sense, and then comparing control and treated.

Ideas of functional data analysis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis 
may be relevant here.

In any case, can you get all your data on one plot? That sounds possible in principle.